# Well-known binary (WKB) format for a Polygon?

Tags: mysql, binary, mariadb, geospatial

All [the examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry#Well-known_binary) I've seen are for a simple POINT, but then they don't go into detail about how a POLYGON is represented.

What's the binary format for a 2D polygon?

1 byte for endianness, 4-byte int 3 meaning polygon, and then what?

---

Here's the binary for `PolyFromText('POLYGON((1 2,3 4,1 2))')`:

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 01 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 03 00 00    ................
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    .......ð?.......
00000020  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 10    @.......@.......
00000030  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    @......ð?.......
00000040  40                                                 @
```

It looks like it actually begins with a point?? Not sure what's going on here.

---

I've partially reverse engineered it.

```
select hex(PolyFromText('POLYGON((255 65535))'));

00000000            srid
01                  little-endian
03000000            polygon
0100000001000000 
0000000000E06F40 =  bin2hex(pack('e',255))
00000000E0FFEF40 =  unpack('e',hex2bin('00000000E0FFEF40'))
```

Haven't figured out what `0100000001000000` means yet.

---

It's two little-endian int32s. The first one always seems to be 1, the second is the number of points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polygon is a list of loops - first loop is shell of the polygon, and following loops are holes.

Polygon format is

- endianness flag
- 3 for polygon marker
- a 4-byte integer for number of loops
- loops

Each loop is

- number of vertices in the loop
- vertices (points)

Each point is

- longitude (double)
- latitude (double)

Comment: Ahah! What about the SRID? Is that optional? Or that's specific to the `EWKB` format which it looks like MariaDB uses.

Comment: Yep, SRID is EWKB feature